# How to set up simple HTTP server in Python 3.5 on Windows 10?

Tags: python, cgi

I am using python 3.5 IDLE, windows 10 and edge as browser.  I am facing issue while executing following simple code on simple HTTP server.  Issue is that it just displays the code after removing the HTML tab instead of showing “ Hello World! This is my first CGI program “.
Have I missed anything in setting of environmental variables etc?

Code:

```
import cgi, cgitb
print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
print ('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print ('<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>')
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

Comment: Why do you use cgi? Try f.e. “Flask“, it is much easier

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am just following python tutorial. Will definitely try flask,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get the code you have written working without issue, so perhaps it is an issue in your calling environment.

If you see this section of the cgi docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html then

> If it’s installed in the **standard cgi-bin directory**, it should be possible to send it a request by entering a URL into your browser of the form:
>
> ```
> http://yourhostname/cgi-bin/cgi.py?name=Joe+Blow&addr=At+Home
> ```

as well as the cgi section of the python HTTP Server docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler

> ### cgi_directories
>
> This defaults to `['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']` and describes directories to treat as containing CGI scripts.

What we need then is a certain folder structure, as in:

```
cgi-test
 |
 +-- cgi-bin
    |
    +-- test.py
```

with `test.py` containing your code as above.

Now to start the python HTTP Server navigate to your enclosing folder (ie `cgi-test`) and type in `python -m http.server --cgi 8000` and assuming your python executable is on your system path you should get a response like: `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`

Finally navigate using your browser to `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.py` to see your rendered page.

**Note:** `cgi-test` could be anything, for instance C:\Users\Username\Website, D:\MyServer\ ...

**Note2:** *If I move the `test.py` file up one level to the cgi-test folder I get a result similar to what you describe (ie I see the code rather than the rendered page)*

**Note3:** *I am running on Windows 7 with python 3.4, but it should hopefully be similar enough that you should be able to follow the same procedure.*

Comment: Thank you very much. It did work.  I have to start server from cgi-test directory.  Is there any way, wherein I can start the server from any directory?

Comment: Hmm, `cgi-test` was an example folder, this could be called anything, the important point was that `cgi-bin` folder should be in the top level of your web server (where you start server from). You seem to be able to add other default directories by adding them to the `cgi_directories` data member - as described in the second link above. I also second @tonka when he suggests checking out Flask... Also feel free to mark this as the solution if it has helped you...